# Inspector to temporarily modify UI elements of Windows Desktop Applications

Tags: windows, user-interface

Is there a way to inspect and temporarily modify controls and elements of a Windows application like how a browser has dev tools which allows for doing that to web pages?

I've used AutoHotkey's Window Spy with ControlSetText to do this to a limited degree, but am looking for something more sophisticated.

The context is just wanting to modify the visuals (text and/or graphics), not any underlying functionality like what clicking the button does.

Comment: Are you looking for Windows UI Automation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32

Comment: @SimonMourier that's interesting but I'm looking for something which can be used with any app regardless of any framework or prep that has been done in advance. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what UI Automation is about, work with any app. You won't find anything better anyway if the app is not written to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Detective allows for this (https://windowdetective.sourceforge.io/)

You can drag and drop "Pick window" onto a control and then do "Edit Properties"

[image]

Comment: This works only for window-based frameworks. Try it on a web page.

Comment: Valid point @RaymondChen - it may only works on some types of apps - I haven't seen anything which can address those but let me know if you're aware of one

Comment: See Simon Mourier's comment earlier. UI Automation is the cross-framework standard for this, but it is designed for automation, not hacking.